# How to split data X,Y in to train and test?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, svm, ml.net

Hey everyone) i am developing aplication for stock prediction(college project) in order to train
SVM Model i need to split my data in to train and test sets `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test`
I got X and Y double colection which i need to split. In python i know there functions which easaly splits data in to four variables `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test` but i can't find something like this in c#. On Microsoft oficial website i found only this example but as i mentioned it only accepts one variable and in my case SVM won't be working correctly.
I've heard about microsoft ML project but it splits only one variable.
I've tried this example but as i mentioned it accepts only one veriable and provides train and test split

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();// Creating the ML.Net IHostEnvironment
var dataview = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(examples);

var split = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataview, testFraction: 0.1, samplingKeyColumnName: "Group");

var trainSet = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<DataPoint>(split.TrainSet, reuseRowObject: false);

var testSet = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<DataPoint>(split.TestSet,reuseRowObject: false);
```

Maybe anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dataset creation

First merge your X, Y columns to form a single dataset (or IDataView) for each of the train & test.

You can then split either of the merged datasets to create additional holdout/validation splits. In the stock dataset, I'd split the training set to train+validation (or use cross-validation on train) to avoid leakage in the test dataset and ensure the metrics from the test dataset are accurate.

#### Leakage

Hopefully your `samplingKeyColumnName: "Group"` column is partially protecting you from the leakage of randomly splitting a time-series dataset. The splitting will cause your model to learn on datapoints both newer and older than your scoring data. The leakage will artificially cause your metrics to be higher than expected. Splitting based on stock ticker will still leak to some extent as for example, knowing the future of GOOG, will give me useful information about predicting MSFT. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)

Generally, you'd want to split based on time for a time series dataset (oldest in train, newer in validation, and newest in test); or use rolling-origin cross validation.